# Creating cursor data database located on external sdcard

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, sd-card

I have an application that tries to read a database located on the external card. The point is that the database opens because it warns me Toast, but I can not load a cursor with the field data of the table name. The database is called bas schedule and within it there is a table llamda contact with a column called names. The code I'm using is as follows:
        try {

```
        SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/storage/external_SD/.Sistem/agenda", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);            
             Toast.makeText( this, "BD1 abierta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();                
            }    
            catch (Exception e)
            {   
                 Toast.makeText( this, "No se pudo abrir BD1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();   
            } 
    try {
        Spinner spn2 = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spn2);            
        Cursor cur1 = baseDatos.rawQuery("select nombre from contactos ORDER BY nombre ASC", null);
        startManagingCursor(cur1);
        String[] from = new String[]{"nombre"};
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur1, from, to);
        mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         spn2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
     }
```

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void startManagingCursor (Cursor c)
```

This method was deprecated in API level 11.
Use the new CursorLoader class with LoaderManager instead; this is also available on 
older platforms through the Android compatibility package.
Check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html